# When to use React createFragment?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm rendering a `ListView` in React Native, managed to fix this React warning but I don't understand how and why it works:

> Warning: Any use of a keyed object should be wrapped in React.addons.createFragment(object) before being passed as a child.

```
// This array generates React Fragment warning.
var data1 = [{name: "bob"}, {name:"john"}]

// This array works, no warnings.
var data2 = [React.addons.createFragment({name: "bob"}),
             React.addons.createFragment({name: "john"})]

// This also works, no warnings.
var data3 = ["bob", "john"]

class Listings extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2})

    this.state = {
      dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(data),
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
       <ListView
         dataSource={this.state.dataSource} 
         renderRow={(rowData) => <Text>{rowData}</Text>} />
    )
  }
}
```

What is a React Fragment? When is it needed in React? Why does a keyed object cause this warning?

Answer (score 16):

I am dividing my answer in 2 sections to cover the 2 main points I see in your question.

## Section 1: What is a React Fragment?

In order to explain what a **React Fragment** is, we need to take step back and talk about **React Keys**.

**Keys** help React identify which items have changed, are added, or are removed. They should be given to the elements inside an array to give the elements a stable identity (uniqueness).

The best way to pick a key is to use a string that uniquely identifies a list item among its siblings. Most often you would use IDs from your data as keys. Here's a practical example:

```
render() {
    const todoItems = todos.map((todo) =>
      <li key={todo.id}>
        {todo.text}
      </li>
    );

    return todoItems;
}
```

It's important to note that the `todoItems` is actually an array of `<li>` elements.

Knowing that, let's move on to why you receive a warning in your use-case.

In most cases, you can use the `key` prop to specify keys on the elements you're returning from render, just like the example above. However, this breaks down in one situation: if you have two sets of children that you need to reorder, there's no way to put a key on each set without adding a wrapper element.

Here's the classical example from the [recently updated React docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/create-fragment.html#overview):

```
function Swapper(props) {
  let children;
  if (props.swapped) {
    children = [props.rightChildren, props.leftChildren];
  } else {
    children = [props.leftChildren, props.rightChildren];
  }
  return <div>{children}</div>;
}
```

The children will unmount and remount as you change the `swapped` prop because there aren't any keys marked on the two sets of children.

To solve this problem, you can use the createFragment add-on to give keys to the sets of children. [Follow the enhanced example, using the `createFragment` here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/create-fragment.html#arrayltreactnodegt-createfragmentobject-children).

---

## Section 2: But why you are getting this warning?

Anyways, the error you're getting error happens simply because you try to interpolate a JavaScript object (rather than a JSX element or string) into some JSX.

Although the error message suggests using `createFragment` to fix this, the reason is because you're interpolating a variable into some JSX that is not a string or JSX element, but is in fact some other kind of object!

Such a misleading warning in your use-case, isn't it? :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can import Fragment from 'react' as:

```
import React, { Fragment } from "react";
```

Then update your render function as:

```
render() {
    return (
       <ListView
         dataSource={this.state.dataSource} 
         renderRow={(rowData) => {
                               <Fragment key={passsKey}>
                                  <Text>{rowData}</Text>
                               </Fragment>
                             }} 
       />
 )}
```